# $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Prove that : for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exist points $a = x_0 \lt x_1 \lt ... \lt x_{n-1} \lt x_n = b$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Sorry for the unspecified title. There's a word limit for that and I couldn't fit it in.

> Let $a \lt b$ and $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Prove the following: for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exist points $a = x_0 \lt x_1 \lt ... \lt x_{n-1} \lt x_n = b$ such that for any $k = 1,2,...n$ we have $$sup_{[x_{k-1},x_k]} f - inf_{[x_{k-1},x_k]} f \lt \epsilon$$

This seems faily easy but I can't set up the partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ for which this can happen. I know that $f$ being continuous on a bounded closed interval yields that it is bounded. But I can set up the sub intervals for which the criterion holds.

Please any suggestions? A little one may be of great help. I think I maybe able to solve it on my own,just need a nudge.

Comment: **Hint:** Continuity on compact implies uniform continuity.

Comment: @Surb Let me elaborate on your hint. Then you tell me if I'm right

Comment: Uniformly continuous means that I'll get a $\delta \gt 0$ corresponding to a $\epsilon \gt 0$ for which $|f(x)-f(y)| \lt \epsilon$ for any $x,y$ such that $|x-y| \lt \delta$. Now if I take a partition whose norm is less than this $\delta$ then I'm done as $f$ also attains it's bounds in these sub-intervals. Is that correct?

Comment: yes it's correct.